# If I was deported from Canada when I was underage, am I able to have a layover in the US?

Tags: usa, layovers

If I was deported when I was underage not for any criminal records, our process was simply denied. Am I able to have a layover in the us with a connecting flight to to Switzerland? I am also a Spanish citizen

Comment: Also a Spanish citizen in addition to some other citizenship?

Comment: Were you actually deported, or were you merely denied entry? Do you (or your family) retain any Canadian paperwork about it?

Comment: Note than being denied entry is not the same as being _deported_ and you should find out exactly what happened so that you are later able to correctly fill the paperwork you will need for traveling.

Comment: surely there are better ways to go from Spain to Switzerland than one implying a layover in the US...

Answer (score 27):

The best approach here is to apply for ESTA, which you will need to transit the US on the visa waiver program.  ESTA is valid for two years, so you can apply now to see whether it is granted.

Pay close attention to answering all of the questions truthfully.  If they ask you whether you were ever deported from the US, you should answer "no," but if they ask you whether you were ever deported from any country, you should of course answer "yes."

If the ESTA is denied, you should apply for a visa.  During the visa application, you will be able to explain that the deportation occurred when you were a minor.  It should not be held against you.

If the ESTA is granted, you can travel without a visa.